# Magento Dashboard > get total orders and totals shipment for a date

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'd like to add a number of statistics to the magento admin dashboard, see attached image. I would need a php script that would count the number of orders for a certain status on a certain date.

For example: count all orders with status 'processing' on date 'today'.

For shipments: count all shipments that on date 'today'.

Thanks for all the help!

[image: Magento Dashbaord Statistics]

Comment: create a module for this functionality.

Comment: Module would be awesome, I think this would be useful to many more.

Answer (score 0):

It requires some magento knowledge to integrate such scripts in your dashboard, but the statistics you require are certainly possible. You can get status history information from the 'sales/order_status_history' model and current order information from the 'sales/order' model.

Did you check if any of the statistics you need are available in the Reports section by the way?

Comment: Hi Lucas,
I just realised that magento stores the shipments. The script wouldn't have to a look at which orders changed status. Instead, the script could just count all shipments on date 'today'